# Changing folder name in batch file, Win 11 Pro

Tags: batch-file, windows-11

This is part of a batch file (that worked fine in Win 7 & 10, but not in Win 11).  Earlier, the batch file creates a folder named "Today" and files are copied to it.  This is supposed to change the folder "Today" to a date, formatted as YYYY-MM-DD:

```
setlocal enableextensions 
set name=%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~7,2%
Rename "Today" "%name%"
```

This is what happens:

```
D:\>set name=5/23-e -05
D:\>Rename "today" "5/23-e -05"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Windows 11 has tighter security. What is the path that Windows 11 cannot find?

Comment: @John I think the issue is with the value of `name` being hot garbage compared to what it should be `5/23-e -05` vs `2023-09-05` :p

Comment: What's the output of `echo %date%`

Comment: ^^^ at a guess, it's `Tue 09/05/23` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

```bash
@echo off && cd /d D:\

for /f delims^=. %%i in ('
     wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr [0-9]
   ')do set "_date=%%~i"
    
Set "_name=%_date:~0,4%-%_date:~4,2%-%_date:~6,2%"

Rename "Today" "%_name%"
```

---

The **[`%date%`](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html)** variable will always display the date in the format according to language, country, and/or in a customized/configured format by the user, that is, it does not follow a fixed layout/pattern, where we can work in a predictive way, and, consequently, manipulate the output string, relying on a fixed/predictable layout

```bash
The default output from DATE /T in the United States is "1/23/1997" but this is dependent on the country/locale.
The default short date and time formats for a selection of countries are as follows:

 Country/language  CountryCode Locale Date_format  Time_format

   Argentina-Spanish     054   2C0A   23/01/1997   9:45:30 am
   Australia             061   0C09   23/01/1997   9:45:30 AM
   Austria               043   0C07   23.01.1997   09:45:30
   Brazil-Portuguese     055   0416   23/01/1997   09:45:30
   Belgium-French        032   080C   23/01/1997   09:45:30
   Belgium-Dutch         032   0813   23/01/1997   9:45:30
   Canada-French         002   0C0C   1997-01-23   09:45:30
   Canada-English        002   1009   01/23/1997   9:45:30 AM
   China/PRC-Chinese     086   0804   1997/1/23    9:45:30
   China/HK-Chinese Trad 852   0C04   23/1/1997    9:45:30
   Czech Republic        042   0405   23.1.1997    9:45:30 
   Denmark               045   0406   23-01-1997   09.45.30
   Finland               358   040B   23.1.1997    9:45:00
   France                033   040C   23/01/1997   09:45:30
   Germany               049   0407   23.01.1997   09:45:30
   Greece                030   0408   23/01/1997   9:45:30 μμ
   Hungary               036   040E   1997.01.23.  9:45:30 
   India-Hindi           091   0439   23-01-1997   09:45:30
   India-Bengali         091   0445   23-01-97     09.35.00 
   India-Telugu          091   044A   23-01-97     09:45:30 
   Italy                 039   0410   23/01/1997   09.45.30 
   Japan                 081   0411   1997/01/23   9:45:30
   Netherlands           031   0413   23-01-1997   9:45:30 
   Norway                047   0414   23.01.1997   09:45:30 
   Poland                048   0415   1997-01-23   09:45:30 
   Portugal              351   0816   23-01-1997   09:45:30 
   Spain                 034   0C0A   23/01/1997   9:45:30 
   Sweden                046   041D   1997-01-23   09.45.30
   Switzerland-French    041   100C   23.01.1997   09:45:30
   Switzerland-German    041   0807   23.01.1997   09:45:30
   Switzerland-Italian   041   0810   23.01.1997   09:45:30
   United Kingdom        044   0809   23/01/1997   09:45:30
   United States         001   0409   1/23/1997    9:45:30 AM
```

An alternative method to get predictive/predictable output would be to use wmic in a for loop filtering, as `wmi` will always return the same strings and regardless of country, customizations, user settings, windows version, etc...

With **[`Wmic OS Get localdatetime /value`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)** returns the strings:

```
LocalDateTime=20230906105958.182000-180
```

A `For /F loop ( wmic | filter Regex )do..`, would it be:

```bash
for /f delims^=. %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr [0-9]')do set "_date=%~i"

set "_date=20230906105958"
```

Using **[String Manipulation # Extract a Substring by Position](https://dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

```bash
for /f delims^=. %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr [0-9]')do set "_date=%%~i"
echo/%_date:~0,4%-%_date:~4,2%-%_date:~6,2%
```

Results:

```bash
2023-09-06
```

---

Take the time to get details on references pertinent to your question and answer:

- **[How do I get current date time on the Windows command line in a suitable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)**
- **[What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)**

---

---

## Additional resources:

- [`Cd` | `ChDir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [`For /?`](https://dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [`For /F /?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)
- [`PathPing /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why I was getting the error "The system cannot find the path specified."  I was testing it at the root of D drive.

Comment: Echo %date% = Wed 09/06/23

Comment: This answer worked perfectly.  Thank you.  for /f delims^=. %%i in ('
     wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr [0-9]
   ')do set "_date=%%~i"
    
Set "_name=%_date:~0,4%-%_date:~4,2%-%_date:~6,2%"

Rename "Today" "%_name%"

Comment: Just saw this added line.  "@echo off && cd /d D:\"  I actually had most of this in my batch file, on different lines, but have not seen (or used) the "&&".  Played with it and understand.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for testing and commenting too! and ..[plz, see this](https://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: See how to use code in the comment for code: \` code \` == `code`

Comment: To reply to a user, eg Jaromanda X, just add "@ + name" =  **[@Jaromanda X](https://superuser.com/users/504075/jaromanda-x)** And the operator/user is notified of your comment

Comment: See link refer: **[`Cd` | `ChDir`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**